# Temporary Reports in MS Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access, report

Does anybody know if there is a way to generate reports in Access "in memory" where the report doesnt need to be written to the Reports collection? I'm having issues with concurrent users - if the user doesnt have "exclusive access" to the access application the report generation fails, because it requires the previous report to be deleted, which it won't allow. I've looked at the CreateReport method, and I'm not sure if it can accomplish what I'm looking for.

//edited **The templates referenced dont allow any controls(labels, textbotes,etc)**
<strike>The help information associated with the method mentions report templates as well, but I'm not sure if those are some other type of object or just a pre-designed report that you can use as a template.</strike>

Anyways before I start banging my head up against it trying to make it work I was wondering if anybody had used the CreateReport method before or whether there was some other functionality/design that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your application like most every other application your organization deploys. That means you place the software application on each computer. So, when you want to use a program like word, you install it on each work station. And, when you want to use a program like Excel, you install it on each work station. That way, if one person in your organize has a program with word, it don't impact everyone in the company and they all go home while the one person's problem is fixed.

The exact same advice applies with Access. You are now using a development tool that builds software, and like any other program; you install this program on EACH work station. Everyone quite much worked this way in our industry for 20+ years. It is possible that you don't understand the difference between a data file (that word, or Excel or your program) can consume, and that of an application with a UI and code that runs. That program part has traditionally been placed on each computer to isolate programs.

Can you imagine one person having a problem with Excel and everyone else has to go home while that is fixed? Do the same with your software, and the fact that you are writing your own in house software as opposed to purchasing is not an excuse to ignore how you have been deploying all of your other software. I explain the simple process of splitting here:

http://www.members.shaw.ca/AlbertKallal/Articles/split/index.htm

Do the above not only improves reliability, but it also means you can develop on a copy of the next great release of your application while users are working and using the current version. Splitting takes less time then it takes to write this post, and is really much a requirement the instant you deploy code to more then one user.

Comment: Albert I appreciate your effort, but you have interpreted the situation incorrectly. I am working as an outside developer for another company. I understand completely about how software(ui, etc) differentiates from the data it uses(files like .docs, xls files, .mdb, etc. The point of explaining my role was to clarify that I was not in control of the working environment. Getting into re-organizing how the company works with its applications is not in the scope of the contract. The company is well aware of the limitations of their current setup, but haven't taken the steps (yet), of

Comment: changing to a more appropriate solution. This company has been working for over a decade with their current situation, and however insane it may seem to an outsider, they have managed to be productive with their rudimentary setup. With 20+ years experience you are probably aware that there are companies out there that get stuck in the "stone-age", and only make changes as necessary. The financial costs of changing/upgrading their 4 or 5 access applications could be VERY costly. These are not simple access dbs with a couple tables and reports. We are talking about massive amounts of VBA backed

Comment: forms, reports, custom code for importing thousands of records from external locations. It just wouldn't be a trivial thing to migrate. I actually work on the application in a VM, so I dont have to bother reconfiguring everything wherever I may need to make changes. When I make changes to their application, I have to force everyone out of the file, open it in exclusive-mode and then manually copy the individual components in. I wish it wasn't so, but I haven't been green-lighted to re-structure the application, and I'm not sure I'd even want to have that project.

Comment: They cannot possibly have been working smoothly in the single-file mode, unless they were still using Access 97. But if that were the case, you'd be able to make changes to the file while users are in it, so it can't be A97. Whatever they are doing, THEY HAVE TO CHANGE IT. IT IS WRONG. It is your job as a professional outside developer to educate them to the error of their ways and point them in the right direction. If they refuse, then drop them like a hot potato, since if something goes wrong, you're going to get blamed.

Comment: Considering I haven't been working day-to-day with them for the last 10 years I can't qualify the statement that it has been running "smoothly". I think there have always been quirks and headaches, and they have just accepted them as limitations and went about their business. They do not have an internal IT dept., the database was created by an outside developer for them about about 10 years ago. It is Access 2000 file format. I think the main thing to understand is that they are just simple end-users. They don't make changes to VBA, reports, etc. They enter data and run reports

Comment: That they are simple users does not change the fact that their Access developer set it up wrong 10 years ago. It's your duty to change it. If they resist, then you are not going to be able to help them at all.

Answer (score 0):

Most Access apps use two access files: a program one and a db one. The db one contains the data, and each user has a copy of the program one with the tables attached. Reports can then be created in the program's mdb/mde without affecting other users.

If you're using a single file model, then as a workaround, what about generating new reports each time using the user's ID (eg 1234_MonthlyReport) and cleaning them up on exit?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the mde/mdb model, that's an interesting thought. I thought that sort of thing was only with a true client/server app with .adp(s) and sql server. Unfortunately, I've been contracted just to create these reports, and it's one access app of several the company has that are fairly complex with csv imports coming in from hundreds of offsite locations. In other words, I dont have much choice about the environment.

Comment: They are using single file. From what I've seen, deletions and design changes will throw an error, unless you have exclusive access, so cleanup would have to wait, until the last user, or the first user in the morning. It seems like I'd end up with a clunky, brittle solution.

Comment: Using a single file means that whoever implemented it was either a complete novice, or a moron. You can't do it reliably, and it should never have been that way. As to what you call the "MDE/MDB" model, that is completely orthogonal to the question of front end/back end.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible safe or reliable or smooth way of ever sharing a monolithic Access file with both data tables and UI objects (forms/reports/etc.) in it.

So, first off, the app MUST BE SPLIT.

You can't get around this. You won't be able to ever enhance their app unless you do all your work at midnight when nobody is in the file working.

Secondly, once it's split, every user should get an individual copy of the front end, since sharing a front end is not just a blocking condition for making alterations to it, but also very easily leads to corruption of the front end (which means nobody can work).

It is your job as outside consultant to fix their problems. You have to educate them on what they are doing wrong. You claim it's been working for them, but it's obviously *not* working, or you'd be able to create the new reports for them. Since you can't IT'S NOT WORKING.

The other thing they need to be told:

Whoever implemented it the way it is now WAS DOING IT WRONG.

I've been developing in Access since 1996, and I've never even onced distributed a production app in anything but a split architecture with a front end on each workstation. That was the right way to do it in 1996 (with Access 2) and it's even more the right way to do it post-Access 2000 (when the monolithic Access project was introduced that prohibited edits to front end objects except when the designer had exclusive access).

So, they have to change or you'll not be able to do your work.

You can also point out that they were in a very dangerous and precarious situation where any number of things could have easily gone wrong and corrupted the front end at any time and forced everyone out of the application.

If they don't want to hear it, then say "thank you very much -- good luck finding someone else to do the job" and run as fast as you can out the door. If you don't, and you acquiesce to their unreasonable requirements, you'll get the blame if it doesn't work the way they think it should.

Do you really want things to go that bad? I guarantee they will if you don't switch them over to the proper architecture right now.

Comment: David, thank you for your input. From day one, I explained to them that their situation was improper. I did recommend to them, the adp/sql server model that I was aware of, because I have seen that in production. I'm not an Access guru or claim to be, and I told them that I didn't have the experience to convert them alone, and that there would be significant licensing costs with SQL server. I was unaware of the mde/mdb model, and that is precisely the reason I decided to post on SO, to gather more information. They seem receptive to the change, but unfortunately their business is highly

Comment: seasonal, and they will be unable to make a significant change until april or may. In the meantime, I was able to give them most of the required functionality by exporting everything to excel reports, based on templates. It's not pretty and requires some work on their part to neaten up the reports at the end. I was really hoping to find some way to create temporary reports similar to an unnamed temporary query (createquerydef ("", ...), which would have allowed me change a little bit of structure and get their desired result. I understand it would have been a band-aid for what is clearly a

Comment: poor situation. The company I'm working for is well aware of the limitations of their current setup, but they don't have the means to rectify it themselves - they have had three other programmers attempt to create the reports which were needed, and they ALL must have taken one look at the mess and ran away. So I'm not worried about them pointing the finger at me. In terms of being productive, I just grabbed a copy the the database, and run it inside a VM, which I always have with me, and manually copy the objects back that have changed. I have to keep good notes :) Again, all parties are aware

Comment: the situation is not optimal, and it has very much been a headache to work for them in this environment, but headaches cost money too! I'm not working for free... I will point out to them that I have been made aware that the way they are running it is dangerous and could potentially corrupt their application. That should motivate them to prioritize the change. Thank You

Comment: The problem with creating new reports doesn't have anything at all to do with the back-end database. It's caused by sharing the front end. Upsizing to SQL Server would have absolutely no effect on that problem at all.